# sendgrid. SMTP-over-SSL, or SMTP+STARTTLS

Tags: java, email, ssl, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I've implemented following email sending:

```
Template template = freemarkerConfig.getTemplate(templateFileName);
String html = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(template, props);
logger.debug("Send email to {} with subject: [{}]", Arrays.toString(to), subject);
Personalization personalization = new Personalization();
for (String toEmail : to) {
    personalization.addTo(new Email(toEmail));
}       
Mail mail = new Mail();
mail.addPersonalization(personalization);
mail.setSubject(subject);
mail.setFrom(new Email(from));
mail.addContent(new Content("text/html", html));
Request request = new Request();
try {
    request.setMethod(Method.POST);
    request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
    request.setBody(mail.build());
    Response response = this.sendGrid.api(request);
    logger.info("Response:{}", response);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    logger.error("Exception occurred during email sending", ex);
}
```

I have a requirement that I need to use `SMTP-over-SSL`, or `SMTP+STARTTLS`.

I am not sure what does it mean. Should I use smtp api(instead of web api) for this case? But sendgrid official site recomment to use web api.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only concerned with sending *to* Sendgrid via TLS, just make sure you start it and run the connection appropriately, and it will be sent encrypted.

If you need to make sure all your mail is sent out of SendGrid only via TLS, you can [Enforce TLS](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Settings/enforced_tls.html) as an option on your mail sending. SendGrid always attempts a TLS connection outbound, but will revert to unencrypted if that flag is not set.